# make a jscrollpane (containing a jtable) fill its container

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable with autoResizeMode set to AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN. I have added it to a panel by creating a JScrollPane with the JTable as its child widget, and then adding the JScrollPane to the panel.

I would like to set the size of the JScrollPane viewport to that of the parent JPanel, and have the JTable resize its last column dynamically.

Comment: What did you try sofar ? what exaclty doesnt work ? SHow a simple example that actually runs and describe what isent working.

Comment: in Swing/AWT, the concept of "set size to .." is incorrect - locating/sizing is the job of the LayoutManager, which all behave differently. Developers choose one which produces the result they want to achieve :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) have got implemented [FlowLayou](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)t by defaut, you can place [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) to the [BorderLayout.CENTER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Comment: Downvoted because this answer doesn't actually show the code for what to do, and it's unclear (at least to me) exactly what is being suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you make the JPanel use GridLayout(1,1) and add the JScrollPane to it then you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer on this link [How to make a JTable fill entire available space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467217/how-to-make-a-jtable-fill-entire-available-space) worked perfectly for me.

I did the following

```
myPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
myJtable = new JTable(MyTableModel);
myPanel.add(new JScrollPane(myJtable));
```